# Could not find the task 'C/C++: gcc build active file'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am using C/C++ v1.6.0 extension by Microsoft
and when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run my code in debug mode I receive the following error:
[image]

I read some other posts that suggested configureing `launch.json`, but I don't even have this file:
[image: Structure of the folder]

The content of `tasks.json` is as follow:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you don't have required configuration file then you create it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can try to press F1 and type 'build' or 'debug'. Visual Studio Code has great support for automatically generating such tasks.
You can also look in the Run and Debug pane (button on the left or Ctrl+Shift+D). Maybe there are some hints.

Answer (score 0):

For me my problem was I was using a subsystem of WSL in VS Code. So reinstalling the C/C++ extension off of the market place again in my workspace worked for me. Also, I noticed under your JSON file you have

```
"command": "/usr/bin/clang"
```

And

```
"detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
```

My JSON File is slightly different from yours hope this helps.

[tasks.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOnbj.png)